# Is there an example of JUnit Attachments Jenkins Plugin working?

Tags: junit, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying for the last hour or so to get the following working.  I have my attachments stored in the target directory.  But they are not linked on the test pages at either the class level or the test level.

I have tried every combination of the following:

- putting the attachment folder `target/surefire-reports/[class]/` with the target`/surefire-reports/[class].xml` folder
- `target/surefire-reports/[class.mothod]/` with the `target/surefire-reports/[class].xml`
- putting the attachment folder in target`/testArtifacts/[class]/` and printing `[[ATTACHMENT|target/testArtifacts/[class]/captureDebug.txt]]` in std out
- putting the attachment folder in `target/testArtifacts/[class]/` and printing `[[ATTACHMENT|/var/lib/jenkins/.../target/testArtifacts/[class]/captureDebug.txt]]` in std out

I am running with a slave master setup, not that that should matter.

My Jenkins version is 1.529 and JUnit Attachments Plugin is 1.3.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Attachments+Plugin

I created a simple project that exemplifies this problem, you can get it here:

https://github.com/marklemay/simple-failing-project

It is build with command line maven (`mvn -U -Pci clean integration-test -e`).

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is wrong with your attempt. Please explain in more detail how it doesn't work.

Comment: There should be links on the test pages to the generated test artifacts.  But there are not.

Comment: I didn't look at this for a long while and then (after some Jenkins upgrades) it started working again.

Answer (score 4):

When I first tried to use the JUnit attachments plugin, I thought it was not working, because there seemed not to be any effect. I use Jenkins version 1.528, JUnitAttachment plugin version 1.3, Ant (not Maven) build on master (no slaves) and the approach with `[[ATTACHMENT|...]]` (with absolute paths) in `stderr`. The files where indeed copied to the build results directory in `<JENKINSDIR>/jobs/<JOBNAME>/builds/<DATETIME>/junit-attachments`. The attachements are only displayed on the class level. Does the junit-attachments directory appear in your build results directories?

Comment: "The attachements are only displayed on the class level". This was my case: I expected them to be displayed in every page (e.g. the home page of the test results) but unfortunately they aren't. Thx for the tip, it's not mentioned anywhere else, AFAIK!

Answer (score 1):

Your sample project worked (sort-of) for me when writing the attachment into the expected directory as seen in the diff below. I'm using Jenkins 1.540 and junit-attachments-plugin 1.3, and the project configured as a maven 2/3. I saw the attachments on the page for the test class page.

However, that "sort-of" I mentioned is because your project and attachments has the same problem I'm trying to resolve, when clicking the link for the attachment results in a 404 page.

```
--- a/src/test/Math/MathTest.java
+++ b/src/test/Math/MathTest.java
@@ -14,13 +14,13 @@ public class MathTest {
    public void test1p1e2() throws Exception {

            //does file writing work?
-        String relpath = "target/testArtifacts/";
+        String relpath = "target/surefire-reports/Math.MathTest/";

     (new File(relpath)).mkdirs();
     String root = relpath + this.getClass().getName();
     (new File(root)).mkdirs();

-        File path = new File(root + "/Insight.math");
+        File path = new File(root + "/test1ple2.math");
     FileUtils.write(path, "things are getting SUbtracted!!!!");
```