# Jenkins Test Result to interpret HTML written to stdout/err [aka Screenshots as base64 from Selenium to Jenkins]

Tags: jenkins

My upstream goal is attaching/embedding screenshots into the Test Result of jenkins (especially for failed tests), so that I can see at a glance the screenshot right in the main page of the Test Result (i.e. at `/job/JOBNAME/lastBuild/testReport/`) without having to dig deeper.

I know of the "JUnit Attachments Plugin" but it sucks IMHO (e.g. attachments are only [displayed at the class level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18763948/1797282) ).

I also know of the [data URI "trick"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML), and I would like to integrate it into the jenkins test report.

I managed to have my test write to stdout/stderr the html with the image, i.e.:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

So my downstream problem is now how to have the HTML interpreted by Jenkins.
Is it at all possible? I couldn't find anything, a part from the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).

Thank you.