# Is there any way I can add attachment (image) for each failed test on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've been looking for some kind of way to add an image as an attachment on each failed test result on Jenkins, but I can't seem to find any approach to do this.

Is there any way to add an attachment for each failed test on Jenkins? My goal here is to add an image and visualize it for every failed test on Jenkins.

Comment: Last time I researched this, I couldn't find a way to add an attachment. As a workaround I used `archiveArtifacts` to save the image as an artifact and included the artifact URL in the title of the test case, which makes it a clickable link in Blue Ocean's test results tab. It looks a bit ugly, but it works.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the response - That seems like a very good alternative, but surely a solution must exist to display an image in the test results, considering the size of Jenkins.

Comment: There is [JUnit attachments plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit-attachments/). I couldn't get it to work, but I haven't tried recent version.

Comment: @zett42 It doesn't work for me either. I tried both absolute and relative path pointing to the images. There is also lacking a lot of documentation on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18540263/7571258 ... but the posts are very old.

Comment: @zett42 I managed to get the JUnit Attachment Plugin to work, however it doesn't display the image, but instead display a table which includes the image. I guess that will do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you get it to work? Would you please self-answer here or at the linked question? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the JUnit attachments plugin to work.
To get the plugin to work I added `[[ATTACHMENT|absolute_path_to_file]]`  inside `<system-err> </system-err>` so it becomes like this:

```
<system-err>
[[ATTACHMENT|C:\some\path\file.png]]
[[ATTACHMENT|C:\some\path\file2.png]]
</system-err>
```

One important factor is that each attachment line has to be on its own line. They also explained it in their short documentation.
Then we have to apply the JUnit attachments plugin on the Jenkins. I have added the following line into my Jenkinsfile in my post section.

```
junit(allowEmptyResults: true, keepLongStdio: true, testDataPublishers: [[$class:'AttachmentPublisher']], testResults: '__tests__/results/**/*.xml')
```

The important properties here is the testDataPublishers and keepLongStdio.

Comment: Great! Do the attachments also show up in Blue Ocean or is this classic-view-only?

Comment: @zett42 Classic-view only :)